# Adjusting CGSize according to the UILabel Font Size

Tags: ios, objective-c

The `CGSize` which I am getting is longer in height than the label font. 
I want to remove the top/left/right/bottom padding between the text and the UILabel edges so that the UILabel frame just fits the text it contains.

This is the code I am using....

```
NSString *ad=@"hello"; 
NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]}; 
CGSize textSize = [ad sizeWithAttributes:fontAttributes]; 
bc =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, textSize.width, textSize.height)]; 
bc.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]; 
bc.text=ad; 
bc.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; 
bc.layer.borderWidth = 1.0; 

[self.tap addSubview:bc];
```

Comment: This is the code i am using....                                                          NSString *ad=@"hello";
NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50]};
 CGSize textSize = [ad sizeWithAttributes:fontAttributes];
 bc =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, textSize.width, textSize.height)];
 bc.font= [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
  bc.text=ad; bc.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  bc.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
  [self.tap addSubview:bc];

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: CGSize textSize have height little bit greater than the font height but i wanted the textSize height and font height should be same..

Comment: let's say you write Hello World in UILabel with Verdana font size of 20px. Now you want height and width of label that will have Hello World only? If yes, then use sizeToFit and resize label accordingly...

Comment: i just have to use single word.. and i tired to use sizeToFit with the Label but still the textSize height is more than the Label Font size height

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to get `CGSize` textSize to allocate your `UILabel`.

Using autolayout in your label:

1. Add your label top,leading, trailing constraints in your xib.
2. Set `numberOfLines` property to 0
3. Set `preferredMaxLayout` width in your VC(if your development target < iOS8)
4. Set whatever text you want.

Comment: yes.. i know i do not have to get CGSize textSize to allocate UILabel... but for some reason i have to use CGSize.The problem is the CGSize textSize have height little bit greater than the font but i wanted the textSize height and font height should be same...   but still thanks for your answer... it will surely help me or someone else in future....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the property of sizeToFitContent if you have dragged it in view. Programmatically, you can try sizeToFit.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the Label font size and don't want to fit the Label with CGSize.  i just want that the CGSize should have exact height with the Label Font Size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NSString *mytext = @"some random text";
    UILabel *someLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 100)];
    someLabel.text = mytext;
    someLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    someLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [self.view addSubview:someLabel];

    // For single line
    someLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    someLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 8;
    someLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    // For multiple lines
    someLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    someLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(someLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize expectSize = [someLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
    someLabel.frame = CGRectMake(someLabel.frame.origin.x, someLabel.frame.origin.y, expectSize.width, expectSize.height);
```

Comment: i have to use only single words in the Labels and don't have any problem with the Label font size. i just want that the CGSize should have exact height with the Label Font Size